# ANTLR reports error and I think it should be able to resolve input with backtracking

Tags: antlr, grammar, backtracking

I have a simple grammar that works for the most part, but at one place it reports error and I think it shouldn't, because it can be resolved using backtracking.

Here is the portion that is problematic.

```
command: object message_chain;
object: ID;
message_chain: unary_message_chain keyword_message?
             | binary_message_chain keyword_message?
             | keyword_message;
unary_message_chain: unary_message+;
binary_message_chain: binary_message+;
unary_message: ID;
binary_message: BINARY_OPERATOR object;
keyword_message: (ID ':' object)+;
```

This is simplified version, object is more complex (it can be result of other command, raw value and so on, but that part works fine). Problem is in `message_chain`, in first alternative. For input like `obj unary1 unary2` it works fine, but for intput like `obj unary1 unary2 keyword1:obj2` is trys to match `keyword1` as unary message and fails when it reaches `:`. I would think that it this situation parser would backtrack and figure that there is `:` and recognize that that is keyword message.

If I make keyword message non-optional it works fine, but I need keyword message to be optional.

Parser finds keyword message if it is in second alternative (binary_message) and third alternative (just keyword_message). So something like this gives good results: `1 + 2 + 3 Keyword1:Value`

What am I missing? Backtracking is set to true in options and it works fine in other cases in the same grammar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a case for PEG-style backtracking, because upon failure that returns to decision points in uncompleted derivations only. For input `obj unary1 unary2 keyword1:obj2`, with a single token lookahead, `keyword1` could be consumed by `unary_message_chain`. The failure may not occur before `keyword_message`, and next to be tried would be the second alternative of message_chain, i.e. `binary_message_chain`, thus missing the correct parse.

However as this grammar is LL(2), it should be possible to extend lookahead to avoid consuming `keyword1` from within `unary_message_chain`. Have you tried explicitly setting `k=2`, without backtracking?

Comment: Thanks for response. Rest of my grammar required backtracking, so I couldn't turn it off (antlr wouldn't compile grammar), but your answer inspired me to redo my grammar and I did. Now it doesn't require backtracking and the problem from the question is gone (and I didn't set `k` anywhere in the code explicitly). So, this answer did solve my problem. Thanks :)